# Why does %in% return false when matching string?

Tags: r, substring

Can someone explain why %in% returns false in this case? The string `<sentiment>` exists in the larger string.

```
> x<-"hahahaha <sentiment>too much</sentiment> <feature>doge</feature>."
> "<sentiment>" %in% x
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: `%in%` matches R objects, not words within a string. Maybe you want `grepl`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%in%` checks whether the former element matches any of the elements in the latter. In this case `x` only has the *element* `"hahahaha <sentiment>too much</sentiment> <feature>doge</feature>."`, not `"<sentiment>"`, so `"<sentiment>" %in% x` returns `FALSE`. For example, the following returns `TRUE`:

```
y = c(x, "<sentiment>")
# > y
# [1] "hahahaha <sentiment>too much</sentiment> <feature>doge</feature>."
# [2] "<sentiment>" 

"<sentiment>" %in% y
# [1] TRUE
```

If you want to check whether `"<sentiment>"` is a *substring* of `x`, use `grepl`:

```
grepl("<sentiment>", x, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE
```

or use `str_detect` from `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_detect(x, fixed("<sentiment>"))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

`%in%` is the `match` operator, equivalent to the [`match` function](https://www.r-bloggers.com/match-function-in-r/).  It searches for an object in a vector (or similar), not an substring in a string.

To find in a string, use one of the [pattern matching functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html), such as `grep` or similar.